# Can not install anything with apt due to libssl1.1 dependency

Tags: apt, 20.04, package-management, upgrade, dependencies

When I run `sudo apt upgrade` from the terminal it gives an error.

Output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libssl-dev : Depends: libssl1.1 (= 1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.18) but 1.1.1f-1ubuntu2 is installed
 libssl1.1 : Breaks: libssl1.1:i386 (!= 1.1.1f-1ubuntu2) but 1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.18 is installed
 libssl1.1:i386 : Breaks: libssl1.1 (!= 1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.18) but 1.1.1f-1ubuntu2 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution)
```

Could someone give me some tips/hints to fix this issue? I am giving some information of my device.

Output of `uname -a`:

```
Linux milon-bs 5.15.0-75-generic #82~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jun 7 19:37:37 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Output of `lsb_release -crid`:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

Output of `sudo apt-cache policy libssl-dev libssl1.1`:

```
libssl-dev:
  Installed: 1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.18
  Candidate: 1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.19
  Version table:
     1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.19 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 Packages
 *** 1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.18 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.1.1f-1ubuntu2 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     1.1.1-1ubuntu2.1~18.04.23 500
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 Packages
libssl1.1:
  Installed: 1.1.1f-1ubuntu2
  Candidate: 1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.19
  Version table:
     1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.19 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 Packages
 *** 1.1.1f-1ubuntu2 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.1.1-1ubuntu2.1~18.04.23 500
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: You have a `bionic-security` source listed. Since those sources are usually removed automatically during a release-upgrade, that presence suggests that your migration from 18.04 to 20.04 went wrong.

Comment: Most users do not need `libssl-dev`, since most users are not SSL developers. If you are not an SSL developer, then you perhaps followed Bad Internet Advice to install it. All advice from that source is suspect. Uninstall that package.